# What is RestrictionPolicy and how do I make it shut up?

Tags: android

A customer is complaining that an audio jack MSR doesn't work.  There's nothing in the log they sent me that clearly points to what the problem might be.  But there are some suspicious items that may or may not be related to each other or to the problem with the MSR.  I want to find out what these things mean so I can rule them out as causes.

First, the log they sent me covers seven minutes and is over 630,000 lines, of which 580,000 lines are this:

`08-05 10:37:56.042 D/RestrictionPolicy(  788): isAudioRecordAllowed : true`

That works out to over a thousand lines of spam per second.  The only thing I could find related to restriction policies was [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), and it mentions nothing about audio.  I want to find out what this spam is not only to rule it out as the problem, but also to make it shut up.

The other suspicious item is this:

```
08-05 10:37:49.124 E/DatabaseUtils(  788): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
08-05 10:37:49.124 E/DatabaseUtils(  788):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:12767)
08-05 10:37:49.124 E/DatabaseUtils(  788):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:1998)
08-05 10:37:49.124 E/DatabaseUtils(  788):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:574)
08-05 10:37:49.124 E/DatabaseUtils(  788):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:256)
08-05 10:37:49.124 E/DatabaseUtils(  788):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:256)
08-05 10:37:49.124 E/DatabaseUtils(  788):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
08-05 10:37:49.124 E/DatabaseUtils(  788):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

This is suspicious because the very next line shows the MSR API's internal thread exiting.  Searching for this error message turns up some problems with wifi on CyanogenMod.  But the customer is not using CyanogenMod, and the problem has nothing to do with wifi.  Also, in the other examples I found, the stack trace involved application code.  This stack trace is pure system.

Comment: logcat has a filter function where you can see only certain tags.  Teaching them to use that may be the best bet, it would just be one more flag to the logcat command.

Comment: Perhaps... but I'd still like to know why it would spam this over a thousand times a second.  It might be related to the customer's bug report, which right now is no more clear than "it doesn't work."  (It being an audio jack MSR.)

Comment: I have the same Spam, have you found where it comes from?

Comment: @Heisenberg Nope.  I think we ended up replacing the customer's tablet.  I've seen log messages about things trying to run as user -2 in other contexts, always on older Samsung devices.  No idea what caused that, either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I found what was spaming it... It was google! hahaha

I disabled the Google Launcher "Ok google" voice recognition outside the search bar and I don't get that line again.

I have a Korean Galaxy Note4, so this seems to only affect Samsung devices.